# Identify duplicate values in List<Tuple<string, string>>

Tags: c#, list, linq, tuples

List Tuple Item1 = Directory Name whilst Item2 = File Path.

Is there a simple way via Linq or the likes to identify only duplicate values in Item1, thus allowing me to iterate over them to retrieve filepaths from Item2?

I’ve been looking everywhere but most explain how to remove duplicates whereas I’m only interested in all duplicate values.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `tuples.GroupBy(t => t.Item1).Where(grp => grp.Count() >= 2)`. That would return an enumeration of groups, where group.Key is the common Item1 value, and the group itsellf is an enumeration of the matching tuples.

Comment: You could also add `SelectMany(grp => grp)` to "ungroup" into a flat list of `Tuple`s again.